# Postgres: Grant access to future tables to various users

Tags: database, postgresql, permissions, privileges, sql-grant

There are several threads already on this topic. Yet I'm unable to get it done and keep getting "permission denied" errors. I must be doing something very wrong.

My goal: on my postgres-database "mydatabase" I would like to have

1. a large group of users belonging to role "group_x"
2. each member of role "group_x" should have access to a certain schema "schema_x"
3. within that schema, all group-members should be able to create new tables and edit each others (future) tables.

How I'm trying it (roughly):

```
psql -h /var/run/postgresql -p5433 -U postgres

create role group_x;

create role user_a LOGIN INHERIT PASSWORD <password>;
create role user_b LOGIN INHERIT PASSWORD <password>;

grant group_x to user_a;
grant group_x to user_b;

\connect mydatabase;

grant all on schema schema_x to group_x;
grant all on all tables in schema schema_x to group_x;
grant all on all sequences in schema schema_x to group_x;
grant all on all functions in schema schema_x to group_x;

set role group_x;

alter default privileges for role group_x in schema schema_x
    grant all on tables to group_x;
alter default privileges for role group_x in schema schema_x
    grant all on sequences to group_x;
alter default privileges for role group_x in schema schema_x
    grant all on functions to group_x;
```

Thanks for pointing out my errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE group_x`, that means that the privileges are only granted on future objects **created by user `group_x`**.

So you need to specify the user that creates tables in the `FOR ROLE` clause.

Comment: hmm, so this is difficult for me, as I don't know ahead of time which user is going to be creating which tables. I was hoping I would be able to create a user-group to coordinate the privileges and give access to all users of that group. Are there alternatives? Hand out the same user-name and password to all the real-life-users? But then I imagine getting troubles if several people access the database at the same time, using identical user-roles?

Comment: You can run several `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements, one for each user. You could also grant `CREATE` on the schema only to a role common to all users, and they have to `SET ROLE` before creating tables.

Comment: Your clarifications are very helpful. I'll try your first recomendation (running the statements for each new user created). The second recommendation is not working for my use-case, because the tables will likely be created through the QGIS-Software Interface, there's no setting there (that I am aware of) to achieve a role change. I am doing this project in my sparetime, so it migth take me a couple days to report back how it went, but thanks very much for your kind help.

Comment: By changing the above sequence of grants from `alter default privileges for role group_x ... `to `alter default privileges for role user_a ...` and repeating this for all users I get the desired functionality, as suggested by @laurenz-albe. Many thanks. (downside is, I'll have to repeat it all over for each new schema - as we'd like to use new schemas for each project -  as well as for each new user).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event trigger that is triggered on `create table` to always add custom privileges example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grant_CRUD_permissions_on_future_tables()
RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES  IN SCHEMA public TO {user_example};
    grant all on all sequences in schema public to {user_example};
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER grant_CRUD_permissions_trigger
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE grant_CRUD_permissions_on_future_tables();
```